# Need Help Combining Two MySQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not amazing at SQL and can't figure out how to do this. Here are the two queries I have at the moment.

```
SELECT TicketID_PK, SubProjectID_FK, ProjectID_FK, CustomerID_FK, TicketDate, TicketNumber, 
SignOff, WorkOrder, ClientPO, TicketType, Description, Processed 
FROM Tickets 
INNER JOIN CustomersSubProjects ON Tickets.SubProjectID_FK = CustomersSubProjects.SubProjectID_PK 
INNER JOIN CustomersProjects ON CustomersSubProjects.ProjectID_FK = CustomersProjects.ProjectID_PK 
WHERE TicketID_PK = 1

SELECT ROUND(WCB+Vacation+Stat+UIC+CPP+Overhead,2) AS Total 
FROM EmployeeFormula 
WHERE EffectiveDate <= $TicketDate
ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

I'm saving TicketDate as $TicketDate and using it in the second query, but I'm sure there is a way to combine the two queries to avoid this. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I need to select the EmployeeFormula Total (as shown in second query) by comparing the TicketDate column (in the Tickets table) to the EffectiveDate column. So the results should look like this:

```
TicketID_PK     SubProjectID_FK     ProjectID_FK    CustomerID_FK   TicketDate  TicketNumber    Total
1   1   1   1   2014-01-05  1-0501-00   30.78
```

Comment: Um JOIN EmployeeFormula ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "combine".  You need to show us the definitions of the tables `Tickets`, `CustomerProjects`, `CustomerSubProjects` and `EmployeeFormula`, an example of the output you want, and sample input data in those tables to produce the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like a subquery.

```
SELECT TicketID_PK, SubProjectID_FK, ProjectID_FK, CustomerID_FK, TicketDate, TicketNumber, 
SignOff, WorkOrder, ClientPO, TicketType, Description, Processed, (SELECT ROUND(WCB+Vacation+Stat+UIC+CPP+Overhead,2) FROM EmployeeFormula WHERE EffectiveDate <= TicketDate ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC LIMIT 1) AS Total
FROM Tickets 
INNER JOIN CustomersSubProjects ON Tickets.SubProjectID_FK = CustomersSubProjects.SubProjectID_PK 
INNER JOIN CustomersProjects ON CustomersSubProjects.ProjectID_FK = CustomersProjects.ProjectID_PK 
WHERE TicketID_PK = 1
```

Comment: That was simple, thanks. I haven't really used subqueries before and thought I had to do a join.